# Servlet session management

Tags: java, session, tomcat, servlets

I have a problem with sessions management. I am working on a card game web application (using Ajax, Tomcat, Java). I have a login page, waiting room and game board. So when a person logged in, If there is nobody in the waiting room , I redirect him to the Waiting room and create object user with his session id, response object and nickname. When logged in another one user, and servlet "sees" that there is already user in the waiting room, I created new user, save all his data and redirect him to the game board. Also I need to redirect a waiting user to the game board. But when i tried to do it using its response object actually I am sending response to the second user, and waiting user didn't get the response.
So the question is , how I can redirect waiting user to the game board, after the moment that the second user logged in? Do waiting user need to send request every t milliseconds to the servlet to check if there is somebdy ready to play game? Or there is another way to manage 2 session?

Comment: You need to handle the current users data not just at session level but at application level. This can be done storing the data in [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html). Also, you need to update the waiting client view, for that you can use [Atmosphere framework](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere)

Comment: I think the question is about [server push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) technologies. Start by reading the wiki page and then maybe take a look at the [Atmosphere framework](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere).

Comment: Yes, you could have the user poll every so often, or consider "server push" as Boris mentioned.

Comment: Similar: [In servlets, how to notify all open sessions for a change occurance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44838763/642706).