# In servlets, how to notify all open sessions for a change occurance?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have coded a web app for recruitment portal.
When a user (a session owner) adds a new candidate profile, rest all open session (by different users) needs to be notified that a profile has been added. I have created a toolbar on top of page that would show all new notification, but dont know how to code this event handling. 
Lets say if I keep a static variable and on new profilw addition, I change this variable. 
Is there a way in servlets that we can notify() all open sessions that this static variable's value has been changed?

Comment: Similar: [Servlet session management](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17911648/642706)

Answer (score 0):

**possible duplicate** -> [Push Notification to Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062048/push-notification-to-client)

However if you don't stick with Java platform, it's better to use Firebase in order to send push messages to Javascript clients. [Receive Messages in a JavaScript Client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive?hl=en)

Because I guess your purpose is to send messages for the latest changes to clients, not to use Java and servlets.